# Partials for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there something like the concept of partials for Wordpress?

I want to use different snippets for several pages.
I am not a wordpress developer and will only click the pages together.

So for example I have a page A

that uses snippet A, B, C, and F

and another page B

that uses snippet B, C and G

altogether with some custom text...

Comment: Please show some effort in research before asking on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) from the WordPress Codex.

Codex Example:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'nav' );           // Navigation bar (nav.php) ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', '2' );      // Navigation bar #2 (nav-2.php) ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'single' ); // Navigation bar to use in single pages (nav-single.php) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From a coding perspective, you can take advantage of [`get_template_part()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)